# How to identify provisioning profile in finder

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

I have created 20-25 provisioning profiles time by time.

Now one of my provisioning profile is expired which I have renewed.

My main question is **how can I identify my expired provisioning profile from *Finder*'s provisioning profile folder**?

I am getting difficulty to find it because as all know provisioning profile folder do not contain profile by name. It contains provisioning profiles by some numbers.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: In keychain you can check profiles there you will see expired profile marked as expired

Comment: My question is which numbered provisioning profile in **provisioning profile folder** is related to that expired provisioning profile.

Comment: You can't determine it with number you need to go through keychain or if you know which one is expired, go to developer.apple.com & regenerate & download that profile & use it.

Comment: @iYoung Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Did you got the solution? @Er.Vihar

Comment: But using iphone-configuration-utility you can. @Er.Vihar you can see expiration date and with There Team ID.

Comment: Yes, I got the the solution. @DheerajD I am working in an office where we are not allowed to download and install any software directly. We had a procedure for that. That's why I have not tried that option. But I got my problem solved by simple deleting all the provisioning profile one by one. Thank you all for your answers

Comment: But its is an apple official and it is specially for developer. So must suggest you to use it.  Using that you can manage all profile. Simply find them in finder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can download:

[iphone-configuration-utility](http://iphone-configuration-utility.soft32.com/mac/free-download/)

Using this mac app you can manage your all Provisioning Profile.

[image]

Comment: Thank you brother for your suggestion. I'll try to avail us that software by asking to our respected department.

Comment: Sure @Er. Vihar

Answer (score 2):

In case you determined that one of the profile is expired, you don't even need to worry to delete it.

Just go to developer.apple.com regenerate that expired profile, download & install it & you can use that renewed profile without any hassle.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use 3rd party software, you can simply open the .mobileprovision files in TextEdit.  In the readable data, you will find the expiration dates and the profile name.